# How can I get with fetch() the same results then with fetchAll()?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, fetch

I am selecting data from mySQL database with `fetchAll`:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id, dateTime, fileName, path, size FROM files WHERE project = ?"; 
 $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute([$id]);
 $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The array looks like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["10002E41F35560F492298F50D14B03A1"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
    ["fileName"]=>
    string(10) "monkey.jpg"
    ["path"]=>
    string(59) "Volumes/KFS18050001/18050001/elephant/cat/monkey/monkey.jpg"
    ["size"]=>
    string(7) "8650752"
  }
  ["10008A76CEE6BEEEB8000891094A2931"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["dateTime"]=>
    string(19) "2016-10-12 14:39:43"
    ["fileName"]=>
    string(9) "horse.jpg"
    ["path"]=>
    string(51) "Volumes/KFS18050001/18050001/elephant/cat/horse.jpg"
    ["size"]=>
    string(7) "8306688"
  }
}
```

But when I have more then 500.000 entries in my database then this is too much for the system. The array is not created. It is loading very long and then I get a blank page. The I tried to use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`:

```
 $sql = "SELECT id, dateTime, fileName, path, size FROM files WHERE project = ?"; 
 $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $q->execute([$id]);
 $result = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

With `fetch`, my system can handle the 500.000 entries. But now I do not get the result I need:

```
array(6) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(32) "10002E41F35560F492298F50D14B03A1"
  ["dateTime"]=>
  string(19) "2016-10-12 19:46:25"
  ["fileName"]=>
  string(10) "monkey.jpg"
  ["path"]=>
  string(59) "Volumes/KFS18050001/18050001/elephant/cat/monkey/monkey.jpg"
  ["size"]=>
  string(7) "8650752"
}
```

`horse.jpg` is just not displayed. And the id is now not the key of the array.

Is there any way to retrieve the same result then with `fetchAll` by using just `fetch` or is there a way to not overwhelm the system with `fetchAll` and a lot of entries?

Comment: fetch retrieves one row at a time, so you'd have to loop in order to get more than one entry. But ultimately if you have 500,000 legitimate results, you have 500,000 results. Do you need to display all of them? Perhaps you could do some paging? Perhaps the UI needs redesigning to only display more specific data (e.g. you need more search filters or something)? Hard to know without any context.

Comment: Is that 500 000 or 500?

Comment: @TrevorClarke 500000

Comment: @ADyson I would need to have an array with all of them. Because I need to compare this array with another array. I don't know if array chunks would help with this problem

Comment: why not just use a `LIMIT` in your SQL?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs But Limit is limitting. I need all data

Comment: you need to compare all 500,000 results against something else? is this other array also very big? What exactly are you comparing, and why? I feel like if you explain your actual business requirement there might be a better way to achieve your goal. Perhaps it can be done with a SQL query or something.

Comment: @Jarla do you need it all at once or are you ok with comparing in blocks?

Comment: Yeah, the other array is also this big.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I would be ok with comparing in blocks, if this is possible

Comment: @Jarla where does this other array come from originally? Another database, maybe? Another table? What exactly do you need to compare and why? Like I said, please explain the actual reason and goal for this, the we can see if there is another way. What you're proposing is never likely to be very efficient.

Comment: @Jarla then you can use `LIMIT` to do `LIMIT 0, 100` then `LIMIT 101, 200` and so on (or however big increments you'd like to take) - assign them to different variables so eventually you have like 10 variables taking 50,000 rows at a time, then compare

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs But the amount of the rows are always different. I never know how many rows there will be

Comment: @Jarla you can count rows using `->rowCount` and subtracting x from it :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs. But I am still confused how this would work. I mean the comparison of the arrays would need to be in one process.

Comment: `while($result[] = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_GROUP | PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE | PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){}`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @Jarla how are you comparing arrays? That might be code worth sharing for us to see :)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Like this: `$new_data = array_merge($result,$otherstuff);
                    foreach ($properties as $k1 => $v1) {
                        if (array_diff_assoc($new_data[$k1], $properties[$k1])){
                            $diff[$k1] = array_diff_assoc($new_data[$k1], $properties[$k1]);
                        }
                    }`

Comment: That does the exact same thing as `fetchAll()`...

Comment: What is represented by $otherstuff, $properties and $diff in that example?

Comment: This might be a solution for the problem: https://gielberkers.com/prevent-generic-killed-error-php-script/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I highly doubt you need to load 500,000 images at once, I suggest you try the following.

What I would do is continue using fetchall() but only select the results from the database that you currently need. If you need to load all the images, lets say if you are creating an instagram-type program, I suggest you dynamically load the images and as you scroll down the page, query the database every few hundred images.

You can do this with `limit` in mysql:

```
SELECT ....query here.... LIMIT 0,100
```

and once your user has scrolled down say, 80 images, query the database again with the following:

```
 SELECT ....query here.... LIMIT 100,199
```

This way you will not overload either the database or the client's system with too many results.

Comment: The entries are not all images. It is different kind of stuff

Comment: I do not load the data on the page. I just need to create an array that I need to compare with another array and check if they are similar

Comment: @Jarla the issue is that php is not going to be able to hande an array of length 500 000.

Comment: Yeah, I understand.  Do I need to use array chunks?

Comment: @Jarla You would definitely need to break it up. If you tell us exactly what you are trying to do we may be able to come up with another solution altogether.

Comment: Ok, I have an array `properties`. This array works fine. Now I want to create another array from the mySQL database with the name `$new_data` and I want to compare if these to arrays look exactly the same. (The array `$new_data` is created from the `$result` array) I show here how the comparisan will look like:

Comment: `$new_data = array_merge($result,$otherstuff); foreach ($properties as $k1 => $v1) { if (array_diff_assoc($new_data[$k1], $properties[$k1])){ $diff[$k1] = array_diff_assoc($new_data[$k1], $properties[$k1]); } }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171018/discussion-between-trevor-clarke-and-jarla).